# Which personal pronouns should I use with the 요 form?

Tags: word-choice, formal, pronoun

I know that when I use the ㅂ니다/습니다 form, if I want to say "I" I should say "저" and I know that when I speak in 반말 I should use "나" instead. But what about the intermediate semiformal 요 form, should I use "저" or "나"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both 저 and 나 in a sentence ending with -요.
It is kind of midway between -ㅂ니다/습니다 and 반말 sentence, so it can go both ways.

Examples:

> 내가 먼저 하겠습니다 (X). Very strange.

> 제가 먼저 할게 (X). Even stranger - 저, 제 is never used in 반말.

> 제가 먼저 할게요 (O). Fine - with someone you're not so familiar with.

> 내가 먼저 할게요 (O). Also fine - with someone you're familiar with but not close enough to use 반말.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always, and regardless of what form, 저 and 제 are used in formal contexts opposed to 나 or 내 which are used in informal contexts.

Comment: Technically. But, half-honorific construction is a thing. They sometimes make “-요”-ending sentences with “나” for “I” when they want to respect the listener and don’t want to _humble_ themselves to do that.